# Disassembling C code and inspecting stack

Tags: c, memory, gdb

So I have some simple C code that creates a buffer of size 512 bytes:

```
 #include <sys/types.h>
 #include <netinet/in.h>

 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <ctype.h>

 main(argc, argv)
      char *argv[];
 {
    char line[512];
    gets(line);
 }
```

Does that mean exactly 512 bytes are allocated to the stack for that buffer? Is there a way in GDB we can disassemble the compiled binary we can see things like

- distance between the stack and the return address
- what parmeter gets passed to the 'gets()' function.. such as the address?

I tried stepping through this with GDB but couldn't find ways to inspect things like this

Comment: I'm not sure I understand exactly what you're asking about 'distance between stack and return address'  - you can have gdb print a disassembly of a function by doing for example `(gdb) disas /s main`  See https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Machine-Code.html

Comment: I don't think gdb is necessary here. Check out objdump --disassemble and check out https://linux.die.net/man/1/objdump . You can see the assembler code of the instructions there and you will see that the stack will get decreased by a size of probably 512 bytes - if no alignment is needed.

Comment: There is no `gets` function in C. Please throw away any book that teaches it.

Comment: @n.m it seems to work so maybe hang on to those books

Comment: "it seems to work". Famous last words. Google "gets'.

Comment: Do you have something to actually contribute here?

Comment: 1970s called, they want their pre-ANSI C code back.

Comment: Please get a modern C book. `main()` is not a valid way to declare a function in C, you need to say `int main()`. `gets` is so dangerous  was removed from the language in 2011. I realize these facts might not be interesting to everyone. Some people are happy with stuff that went obsolete many moons ago. If you are one of those people, please say so upfront so that everybody can adjust their expectations.

Answer (score 0):

You could check out the 'strace' command line tool. It will list out all the internal system calls and the corresponding arguments. It will also give you an idea about how much memory is being allocated.

Please note that you should use gets with caution as it has no check for buffer overrun.

From the man page:

*gets() reads a line from stdin into the buffer pointed to by s until either a terminating  newline  or  EOF,  which  it
       replaces with ’\0’.  No check for buffer overrun is performed (see BUGS below).*

Answer (score -1):

You can use printf to show the memory addresses if you want, for example like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
  char line1[512];
  char line2[512];
  char line3[512];
  printf("line1 ptr: %p\n", line1);
  printf("line2 ptr: %p\n", line2);
  printf("line3 ptr: %p\n", line3);
  long int diff = line3 - line1;
  printf("diff between line3 and line1 : %ld\n", diff);
  return 0;
}
```

If you run that you will probably see that the memory locations of line1, line2, and line1 have precisely 512 bytes in between, if the compiler has chosen to lay it out in memory in that way.

Comment: You can't subtract `line1` from `line3` as it yields undefined behavior.